# Meteor Jade: Use helpers functions with parameters

Tags: meteor, pug

I've just started working with Jade and Meteor. And I am a bit stuck.
I have a global helper to format a DATE. But when I call this in Jade I get:

> ReferenceError: formatdate is not defined

This is the helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('formatDate', function(date){
    return moment(moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").fromNow();
});
```

And this is the way I call it in Jade:

```
if Template.subscriptionsReady
    each log in logs
        #{formatDate(log.createdAt)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've figured it out.

Just needed to do:

```
= formatDate(log.createdAt)
```

Wanted to answer my own question to maybe help others with it.